# ASP.NET MVC3: model binding with hidden field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Here's the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Deleted", "Location"))
{
    Html.Hidden("LocationID", Model.LocationID );

    <input type = "submit" value = "Delete" />
}
```

And here's the method that's supposed to receive the data.

```
public ActionResult Deleted(int LocationID)
{
        //Do something with LocationID
        return View();
}
```

When I run the code, **LocationID** is always **null**. Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Html.Hidden` returns an `IHtmlString` containing a hidden field.
However, you aren't doing anything with the returned string.

You need to render the string to the page using an `@`.

Comment: Well, I think I need to read more on Razor. In fact, I thought that, since I was getting intellisense while typing Html., that means I'll get all the magic. Sometime, I'm getting errors telling me that I shouldn't over use @. Now I didn't get any error, but it didn't still work. Thank you now it working after I added @.

Comment: The `@` is used to render the output of an expression to the page.

Comment: `@` is also used to switch from markup blocks to code blocks.

Comment: I might also add that unless you need to set the value on the fly, Html.HiddenFor builds this same element with fewer strings to fat-finger